# Haskell convert type error

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I'm writing a simple program in Haskell that lets user input exponent of the power of 2

```
power a = 2^a
main = do
   number <- readLn
   let x = (read number :: Int)
   power x
```

I figured out that I need to convert `String` to `Int` but i still get following error: `No instance for (Num (IO t0)) arising from a use of 'power'` 
 How do I make it work?

Comment: `read`ing after `readLn` is a bad idea. `readLn = readIO =<< getLine` so you'll read a line, parse that into a `String` (requiring proper quoting and escaping), and then parse that *again* into a number. Just use `readLn`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It helps when you write out the types.

```
power :: (Num a, Integral b) => b -> a
power a = 2^a

main :: IO ()
main = do
  number <- getLine
  let x = read number :: Int
  power x
```

But let's look what these things really return. `power` looks right, but `main` is trying to return a `Num a`, not an `IO ()`. `main` is not meant to return values -- you should do something with them. Maybe you want to `print` the result? `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  number <- getLine
  let x = read number :: Int
  print $ power x
```

Comment: This code compiles fine but when I'm trying to run `.exe` file I get this message: `user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)`

Comment: it's working after changing `readLn` to `getLine` as @HTNW suggested

Comment: @KubaKrzyżyński whoops, yes :)

Comment: @KubaKrzyżyński I suggest you use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read` instead of `read` because `read` is not total.

Comment: Or use `number <- readLn` as in the original.  But there is no need to `read` the `number` -- `readLn` already does that for you.  Just `print $ power number`

Answer (score 1):

Got it running that way - `number` is not an `Int`:

```
power :: (Num a, Integral b) => b -> a
power a = 2^a

main :: IO ()
main = do
  number <- getLine
  let x = read number
  print $ power x
```